# Multiple test versions in the same output pdf using mcexam package

Tags: output, multiple-files, questionnaire, mcexam

I'm using the package [mcexam](https://ctan.org/pkg/mcexam) to build tests with randomised multiple choice questions and randomised answers.

The package usage is as follows:

```
\usepackage[output=exam, numberofversions=58, version=26, randomizequestions=true,randomizeanswers=true]{mcexam}
```

where with the option `numberofversions` I set the number of randomised tests, and with the option `version` I print the 26th version as a pdf output.

I would ask if it is possible to print more versions in the same output pdf (fo example from 1 to 25), without changing the version number every time to create the different output.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to achieve with `\foreach`. But care must be taken, to ensure that you don't end up with duplicate tests.

A randomization table is generated by the `mcquestions` environment, i.e. it will be different for each loop. So the tests will look randomized, but you may end up with duplicates.

To prevent this, `seed` must be set to constant value before the `mcquestions` environment and the `version` must be incremented in each loop.

The incementation is done by `\foreach` and `version` and `seed` are set with `\setkeys`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[output=exam, numberofversions=58, randomizequestions=true,randomizeanswers=true]{mcexam}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,25}{
  \newpage
  \setkeys{mcexam.sty}{version=\i,seed=123}
  \begin{mcquestions}
    \question How much is $2+2$?
    \begin{mcanswerslist}
      \answer two
      \answer[correct] four
      \answer five
    \end{mcanswerslist}
    \question How much is $5-3$?
    \begin{mcanswerslist}
      \answer 1
      \answer[correct] 2
      \answer 3
    \end{mcanswerslist}
    \question How much is $0 \times 2$?
    \begin{mcanswerslist}[fixlast]
      \answer 1
      \answer 2
      \answer[correct] none of the above
    \end{mcanswerslist}
  \end{mcquestions}
}
\end{document}
```

Oh, and next time, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I am trying to compile your answer, but I get this error <Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 30>.